# css: background в разных браузерах

Tags: css, css3

Есть вот такой фон на css:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent,transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно в стиле прописать этот фон для браузеров -webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, -o-? Спрашиваю, потому как не совсем понимаю, как это правильно сделать, т.к. в этом случае добавление к селектору одной приставки мало, и в блоке объявления стилей это прописывается для каждого браузера по-разному.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить соответствующие префиксы к `linear-gradient`.

При этом, если некий браузер поддерживает несколько реализаций, то более новые должны идти позже более старых (поскольку с ними меньше проблем). По той же причине вариант без префиксов должен идти последним.

Замечу, что у браузеров появилась тенденция поддерживать префикс `-webkit`, поэтому его стоит написать первым. Да и вообще, довольно распространённая практика - писать префиксы в порядке убывания длины:

```
-webkit-smth
-khtml-smth
-moz-smth
-ms-smth
-o-smth
smth
```

Возвращаясь к `linear-gradient` и вспоминая, что у `webkit`а есть более старая форма, получим такой порядок:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
```

Ещё про градиенты стоит отметить, что префиксные варианты используют `from`-синтаксис, а принят в итоге был `to`:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, black 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, black 100%);
```

PS: А вообще, стоило бы воспользоваться автопрефиксером или генератором градиентов.

Comment: @LADYX, это штука, которая автоматически добавляет префиксы к css. Раньше была самостоятельной, но сейчас превратилась в плагин для postcss: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

Answer (score 6):

На седьмое июля 2017-го года градиенты поддерживает 94.62% общей массы браузеров, а градиенты без префиксов — 93.75% (согласно статистике Can I use). А значит, добавляете префиксы вы для 0.87% юзеров, при условии, что ваш сайт посещает полноценная выборка пользователей.

Посмотрим, какие браузеры вы поддерживаете, добавляя префиксы:

- Opera Mobile 12-
- Android Browser 4.3-
- IOS Safari 6.1-
- Safari 4...6
- Chrome 25-
- Firefox 15-

И я полагаю, что сознательно тестировать свой продукт в этих браузерах уже бессмысленно. Даже более — по интернету кочует сниппет с градиентами из года в год, разработчики его добавляют «для кроссбраузерности», но уверен, что на практике кроссбраузерность проверяется совсем не в этих браузерах.

P. S. нигде не нашел упоминания, что ИЕ поддерживал когда-либо синтаксис `-ms-linear-gradient`, кажется имеет место карго-культ.

Вывод: добавлять префиксы к линейным градиентам не нужно!

Comment: В соседнем ответе для `-ms` написан комментарий /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ Хотя, пожалуй, это действительно не стоит добавлять в css :)

Comment: @Qwertiy насколько я помню, для ИЕ всегда были фильтр-хаки, странно что этого в ответах не нашлось )

Comment: Они настолько костыльные, что даже в генераторе градиентов их надо включать флажком)) А ещё IE от них тормозит :D

Answer (score 3):

Префикс добавляется не к `background-image`, а к `linear-gradient()`:

`background-image: prefix-linear-gradient(options)`

Ваш случай:

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%); /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%); /* Mozilla Firefox */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%); /* Opera */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%); /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%); /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%); /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
```

Microsoft создали кроссбраузерный генератор градиента **[здесь](https://testdrive-archive.azurewebsites.net/Graphics/CSSGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html)**. Также можете воспользоваться **[этим](http://angrytools.com/gradient/)** сервисом, здесь больше кастомизации.

Answer (score 3):

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: -khtml-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 52%, transparent 52%);
```

А еще есть инструмент для создания кроссбраузерных градиентов: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: В таком порядке не надо.

Comment: Ok, теперь лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще вариант, при котором можно забыть об проблеме.
Прогнать готовый css https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/
Если используеш таск-ранер: gulp-autoprefixer или аналоги.